# replace tag in *dtsConfig file from powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\temp\STA\*.dtsConfig)
$xml.SelectNodes('//ConfiguredValue')|%{$_.'#text'=($_.'#text' -replace '_\d+',[datetime]::Today.ToString('_MMddyyy'))}
$xml.SelectNodes('//ConfiguredValue')|%{$_.'#text'}
xml.Save('C:\temp\STA\*.dtsConfig')
```

from first 3 steps I want to check tag in ConfiguredValue in dtsConfig named PackageDependencies_somedate(20110528) and I want to change PackageDependencies_currentdate(20130619), 
there is change some date to current date and save a file,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHH6h.jpg

Comment: What is your problem? does this code does not work?

Comment: This code works for hard coded file that means if I put somename.dtsConfig then it works but if there are 10 files have extension dtsConfig and I want to make change in all 10 files then files have done changes but could not saved at that path, I need to say for any no of dtsConfig files changes should be done, by the way I was counting files using counter that need to say here still problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like following:

```
ls C:\temp\STA\*.dtsConfig | foreach {
  $file = $_.FullName;
  $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
  $todayStr = [datetime]::Today.ToString('_MMddyyy')
  @($xml.SelectNodes('//ConfiguredValue')) | %{
      $_.'#text'=($_.'#text' -replace '_\d+',$todayStr)
  }
  $xml.Save($file)
}
```

Comment: on 4th line getting error,Unexpected token 'datetime' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:87

Unexpected token '::Today.ToString' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:97

Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:113

Unexpected token '_MMddyyy' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:114

Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:4 char:125